# Junction object confusion

Tags: related-list, relationships, master-detail, junction-object

I have 3 objects **order**,  **order_lines** and **shipment_lines** . So *order* has many *order lines* and many *shipment_lines.*

So I want to display order_lines and shipment_lines fields on a single related list on order.

In an attempt to make Orders as  Junction Object, here's what I found:

1. I already have a Roll-Up Summary (COUNT Order Lines) on **orders** with a Master-Detail relationship with master as Orders .
2. On order_lines I have Lookup to Orders order_number__c
3. On shipment_lines I have  Lookup to Orders shipment_number__c
4. In the end I created a different object Shipping_order to have MD with shipping lines and order lines(I don't prefer this). But now I have to show this table as related list in order.

Is there any possibility that I  can add it to Orders object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fairly certain there will be one `shipment_line` for every `order_line`, you might want to create your junction object `Shipping_Order` as a child of `Orders` then have a M-D between the junction object and `shipment_line` plus another M-D between the Junction object and `order_line`. I believe that will provide you with the single related list you're looking for while also supporting the roll-up summary counts. I don't think the Junction Object will need to have a M-D relationship with `Orders` unless you first break the existing one between `Orders` and `order_line`.

I'm not certain how well this will work for you if there isn't a `shipment_line` for every `order_line`. There may be some sorting issues between the two of them regardless that you'll need to resolve with trying to match between them.

**Edit**
I gave this some further thought and believe your `Junction Object` - `Ship_order` should be in a M-D relationship with `Orders`. In that way when an Order record is deleted, the related Junction Object record will be deleted along with the related `order_line` and `shipping_line` since they'll be in M-D relationships with the Junction Object, making them grandchildren of `Order`. There are valid reasons for all abject to be in M-D relationships and that should be given consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to relate the junction object to the orders object.